# ESB WSO2 payloadFactory Combination of compressed data error

Tags: api, proxy, wso2, compression, wso2-esb

I have a sample,use api invoke Proxy service. in proxy service,i call a endpoint. endpoint return json data,the data is Combination. then i use payloadFactory Meditor analysis that one. but program error!

sample:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="getRTDataHistoryZipProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="method" expression="get-property('transport','method')"/>
            <property name="kksCodes" expression="get-property('transport','kksCodes')"/>
            <property name="uri.var.startTime"
                      expression="get-property('transport','startTime')"/>
            <property name="uri.var.endTime" expression="get-property('transport','endTime')"/>
            <property name="uri.var.resultType"
                      expression="get-property('transport','resultType')"/>
            <property name="uri.var.sampled" expression="get-property('transport','sampled')"/>
         </log>
         <property name="uri.var.kkscode"
                   expression="get-property('transport','kksCodes')"/>
         <property name="uri.var.startTime"
                   expression="get-property('transport','startTime')"/>
         <property name="uri.var.endTime" expression="get-property('transport','endTime')"/>
         <property name="uri.var.resultType"
                   expression="get-property('transport','resultType')"/>
         <property name="uri.var.sampled" expression="get-property('transport','sampled')"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint key="getKksCodeUrl"/>
         </call>
         <enrich>
            <source type="body" clone="true"/>
            <target type="property" property="_payload"/>
         </enrich>
         <log>
            <property name="返回的kks地址:" expression="get-property('_payload')"/>
         </log>
         <iterate continueParent="true" expression="//jsonElement" sequential="true">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <property name="uri.var.restful" expression="//jsonElement"/>
                  <log>
                     <property name="请求的实时值地址" expression="//jsonElement"/>
                  </log>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <http method="post"
                              uri-template="{uri.var.restful}&amp;method=getRTDataHistoryZip&amp;startTime={uri.var.startTime}&amp;endTime={uri.var.endTime}&amp;resultType={uri.var.resultType}&amp;sampled={uri.var.sampled}"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </iterate>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="2" max="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="//jsonObject">
               <log level="full" separator=",">
                  <property name="gethistoryZip代理日志" value="请求历史数据完成！"/>
               </log>
               <log level="full"/>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <soapenv:Body>
                           <jsonObject xmlns="">
                              <BasicResponse>
                                 <succeeded>1</succeeded>
                              </BasicResponse>
$1
  </jsonObject>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                     </soapenv:Envelope>
                  </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//jsonObject/RTDataSets"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

invoke the proxy service,the backgroud error,error info:

```html
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,128]
Message: 在文档的元素内容中找到无效的 XML 字符 (Unicode: 0x1f)。
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
 at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
 at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
 at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
 at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
 ... 40 more
[2016-04-06 11:13:46,666]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:c28c0542-4879-4364-89be-50f4100965e1, Direction: response, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8, Unexpected error sending message back, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><BasicResponse><succeeded>1</succeeded></BasicResponse><RTDataSets><tag>0101A0ABB01DA073H</tag><kksCode>EB001HP1MKA01MK002BA01J1CB001BB03</kksCode><type>1</type><RTDataValues><Value>
```

the result of the plan should be:

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <jsonObject>
   <BasicResponse>
    <succeeded>1</succeeded>
   </BasicResponse>
   <RTDataSets>
    <tag>0101A0ABB05DA001H</tag>
    <kksCode>EB001HP1MKA01MK002BK01J1CB001AA01</kksCode>
    <type>1</type>
    <RTDataValues>
     <Value>
      \u001F\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000mkºô(¯C'ô~\u0012®fþ\u0013;Tï²´è¢ÿµÞìT\b`l·õ\u0015uÌõìÿþ÷Ï?½¾ão¢ï\u0007}þy£Áò\u0005[4õ\u000Fl5^í{ÓYú2Úÿ.­\u001B08ò÷'n:\u0013ì£\u001A¿¿\u001F3\u0000®_ðsÝ¿`)£\u0018ü¶©¼nS
      003ÛìÙ\u0010Ò¡Ú\n\u001FÝ¨WD¯½ê\u0005+È>$F\\\u001BæS
      C\u001AÅ^GBY\u0003¼ËN\u001CWÆ\r´é\u0010ºË¶Wì\u0018ç@P{\u0002\u000BM¸G5\n_\u000FÍ\u001D5và÷ÛHÁøy\u0010¦s#6O0Ó
      Ý\u001A=4©QÙCUUöÐl\u0003\u0011J¤âD\u0004¢TÇ\u001EÇxqÍ&ö0¡MN:qV­¾ÙEÏºn}àT\u0005ÔÈ\u0003¦¬q«D\u0011(HX#~y¹L4;¸L4O0Ó;Ð\u0017ì¡É\u001D«=4÷R¬Û\u0016*Ä(ÈsbÝ¶¼±nS+)\u0005=4yjÕ&,ÝfÅZjÛ+\u001C§·æZwqÚn¥>A³y\u0013Ôv\u0017¢ÅJ}ÔÞ&\u0018jËò\u0004NVÁF\u0013\u0002ÍR¡\u0005Ôöå³\u001FØÛF\u0013Bá\u0012hÞ±ÉD'\u0007øÄflÕ¨²\u0005(h±&k÷m£y¢qû1%­¼ÙFó\u0000ÕYA´\\QõYµ}4y¢a©b\u0013\f^6'SË\u000EåÓ.!Ktâ@Nì5\u000B`r?,Ü+é\u0004·ÜËF\u0015AËU\u0016ØÛÛC©_yh2Å\u000E\u0013Mä\"a¢y
      9\u0006¡:ÙD\u0013¹¥âÄ°\u0019,·aB\u000B¿\u0015Q\fFñÕn±}©Ò+s
      °ËvÖdå
     </Value>
     <Time>1459838790000</Time>
    </RTDataValues>
   </RTDataSets>
  </jsonObject>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i think that the cause of the error is the ESB payloadFactory background parse error,beacuse result contain special chars. but i don't know how to solve. please give me some ideas.. thanks.

Comment: What is your ESB version

Comment: @Ushani I use 4.8.1.